# datastructure for storing class objects recurrsively in collections java

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, recurrence

i have a situation where i am saving departments and subdepartments and employeees.
My database structure is such that parent id of top level departments is 0.
For sub departments under it ,their parent id is the primary key of top level departments so the it becomes recurrsive infinite chain of sub departments.

```
PK | Department | Parent Id
----------------------------
1  | dept1      | 0
2  | dept2      | 0
3  | dept3      | 0
4  | sub_dept1  | 1
5  | sub_dept2  | 1
6  | sub_dept3  | 2
7  | sub_dept4  | 2
8  | sub_dept5  | 2
9  | sub_dept6  | 3
10 | sub_dept7  | 3
```

I have created the following classes:

```
Public Class Departments{
  private String name;
  private Arraylist<Departments> subDepts;
  private Arraylist<Employees> employees;
}


public void parseDepartmentsAndPopulate(Account account, StringBuffer sb){

    try {
        String jsonStr =sb.toString();

        Log.i("DownloadManager", "jsonStr value:" + jsonStr);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model_Departments>>()
                {
                }.getType();

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray getArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("groups");

                list_departments = (ArrayList<Model_Departments>) gson.fromJson(getArray+"", listType);
                //Type listType1 = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model_SubDept>>() {
                //}.getType();
                Log.v("Model_Departments Model", list_departments.toString() );
                Log.v("Model_Departments", list_departments.size()+"length" );
                long autoIncrementId;
                for(Model_Departments m:list_departments)
                {
                    Log.v(LOGTAG, m.name);                      
                    map_departments.put(m.name, "");
                    DepartmentLevels d=new DepartmentLevels(m.name, 0);
                    autoIncrementId=databaseBackend.createDepartment(d);
                    list_topDepartments.add(d);
                    addSubgroups(m,autoIncrementId, account);
                }



                List<DepartmentLevels> list=databaseBackend.getDepartmentLevels();
                for(DepartmentLevels l:list){
                    Log.v(LOGTAG,l.getDepartment_name()+" parent id="+l.getParent_id());
                }
                for (String name: map_departments.keySet()){

                    String key =name.toString();
                    String value = map_departments.get(name).toString();  
                    System.out.println(key + " " + value);  


                } 


                /*for(Model_Departments m:list_departments){
                    if(m.subgroups.size()>0){
                        for(Model_Departments msd:m.subgroups)
                            databaseBackend.createDepartment(new DepartmentLevels(msd.name, 0));

                    }
                }*/

                updateRosterUi();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

```
public void addSubgroups(Model_Departments m,long parentId, Account account)
{   
    if(m.subgroups!=null && m.subgroups.size()>0)
    {
        if(!map_departments.containsKey(m.name))
        {
            map_departments.put(m.name, "");                
        }
        for(Model_Departments msd:m.subgroups)
        {       

            long autoIncrementId=databaseBackend.createDepartment(new DepartmentLevels(m.name, parentId));
            Log.v(LOGTAG,"Model_Subgroups Groups :"+msd.name+" and Autoincrement ID="+autoIncrementId +" Parent Id= "+parentId);
            if(map_departments.containsKey(m.name))
            {
                String value=map_departments.get(m.name);
                map_departments.put(m.name,value.equals("") ? msd.name :value+","+ msd.name );
            }           
            addSubgroups(msd, autoIncrementId,account);
            //Log.v(LOGTAG,"Model_Subgroups Groups"+msd.name+" and Autoincrement ID="+autoIncrementId +" Parent Id= "+parentId);

        }
    }
    if(m.employee!=null && m.employee.size()>0)
    {
        if(m.employee!=null && m.employee.size()>0){
            for(Model_Employees me:m.employee)
            {
                String jid = me.name+"@"+Config.SERVER;
                String name = me.name;
                String subscription = "both";
                Contact contact = account.getRoster().getContact(jid);
                if(contact==null)
                {
                    String cleanJid =me.name+"@"+Config.SERVER;
                    contact = new Contact(cleanJid);
                    contact.setAccount(account);
                    contact.setLocality(me.location);
                    contact.setOrgUnit(m.name);
                }
                //Log.v("IQParser", "inside subscription of contact");
                if (!contact.getOption(Contact.Options.DIRTY_PUSH)) 
                {
                    if(name!=null && !name.equals(""))
                        contact.setServerName(name);
                    //else
                    //contact.setServerName(jid.substring(jid.indexOf("@")+1, jid.indexOf("/")));
                }
                if (subscription!=null) 
                {
                    if (subscription.equals("remove")) 
                    {
                        contact.resetOption(Contact.Options.IN_ROSTER);
                        contact.resetOption(Contact.Options.DIRTY_DELETE);
                        contact.resetOption(Contact.Options.PREEMPTIVE_GRANT);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        contact.setOption(Contact.Options.IN_ROSTER);
                        contact.resetOption(Contact.Options.DIRTY_PUSH);                            
                        contact.setOption(Contact.Options.TO);
                        contact.setOption(Contact.Options.FROM);
                        contact.resetOption(Contact.Options.PREEMPTIVE_GRANT);
                    }
                }
                Log.v(LOGTAG,"Model_Subgroups employee"+me.name);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I am struck at the time of storing these nested values while iterating them in hashmap.I am not able to creating data structure which can hold the tree view of Departments,Subdepartments under them and employees under sub departments.
Can any one please help me to construct the collections datastructure and help me iterate the same.

Comment: when you say "while iterating them in hashmap" do you mean you already stored the database query in hash map? what is the key and value of the hash map ? or are you iterating over resultset?

Comment: How about tree. Let sub departments be children of root department ? Let each node has list of employees.

Comment: you could help us help you by giving the code you have done so far....

Comment: i have done it using hashmap ,can the be any other better way or optimised solution

Comment: I am now sorry I asked for the code..... it contains so many undefined classes (DepartmentLevels?, Model_Departments?) and the map (I assume it is map_departments?) is still undefined. and am I to assume that you get the input sa json?

Comment: give me some time so that i can explain you everything in  better way

Answer (score 1):

this is how I would fill the Departement Class

```
public static class Department {
    String id;
    String name;
    List<Department> subDepartements;
    public Department(String id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.subDepartements = new ArrayList<Department>();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Department> departementsById = new HashMap<String, Department>();
    String[][] values = {
        new String []{"1"  , "dept1"   , "0"} ,
        new String []{"2", "dept2    " , "0"},
        new String []{"3", "dept3    " , "0"},
        new String []{"4", "sub_dept1" , "1"},
        new String []{"5", "sub_dept2" , "1"},
        new String []{"6", "sub_dept3" , "2"},
        new String []{"7", "sub_dept4" , "2"},
        new String []{"8", "sub_dept5" , "2"},
        new String []{"9", "sub_dept6" , "3"},
        new String []{"10" ,"sub_dept7" , "3"}
    };
    for (String[] value : values) {
        String id = value[0];
        String name = value[1];
        departementsById.put(id, new Department(id, name));
    }
    Department rootDepartement = new Department("0", "root departmeent");
    departementsById.put("0", rootDepartement);
    for (String[] value : values) {
        Department departement = departementsById.get(value[0]);
        String parentId = value[2];
        Department parent = departementsById.get(parentId);
        parent.subDepartements.add(departement);
    }
}
```

Comment: will this work for more than one nested level  heirarchy

Comment: Yes, it will work, all the children are linked to their father, regardless of the depth of the level.